# htaccess rewriterule returns incorrect parameter when the url ends with slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a bit confused on why it returns incorrect parameter when the url ends with a slash.

htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^account/dashboard/(.*)/(.*)$ ./account/index.php?page=dashboard&aid=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

when I execute `http://example.com/account/dashboard/65/blitzen12/`

and in the page i can use `$_GET['aid]` it returns `65/blitzen12` and `$_GET['name]` returns empty

but when I remove slash at the end of `blitzen12` in the url it returns correctly which is `65` and `blitzen12`.

can anyone explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^account/dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ./account/index.php?page=dashboard&aid=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

it has to do with [greedy repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). Basically, the dot matches *any* character, including the slash(/)